# How can I train an intent in Watson conversation to accept any number?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, chatbot, watson-conversation

How can we train an intent to accept numbers and identify it as that particular state? 
For example, I'm training an intent to accept a price.

If I type:

- What about 560?

It accepts *560* but if I just type 560 it does not identify.

Comment: So any number would be the intent "price"? Why don't you treat it as an entity? There are built-in ones for numbers and price.

Comment: No. I'm not treating it as an entity. The problem is the built in entity "sys-number" is identified. But it does not map with my intent.

Comment: There is a difference between intents (what do you want to do) vs. entity (objects). Maybe add details on your scenario. Identifying a number as a number (entity) is correct.

Comment: Still no luck! All I need to do is, let any number to be identified under that  intent.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna combine the intent and the entity, you can simply **ADD** one more condition, e.g:

```
if bot recognizes #yourIntent AND @sys-number 
response: "Do you want information about @sys-number?"
```

Or, if you want to identify the number even ONLY it is entered by the user, you can add one more node flow with the condition:

```
if bot recognizes @sys-number 
response: "Do you want information about @sys-number"?
```

If the user just types something about your Intent (You need to train the intent with questions like your example):

```
if bot recognizes #yourIntent
response: "Okay, but, what is the number that you want information?"
```

Obs.: You need to activate the System entity `@sys-number` for it works. And training your `#Intent` with examples to ask questions about. Like @data_henrik said, the `#Intents` are what do you want to do and the `@entity` is the objects.

- See more about [conditions](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/expression-language.html#accessing-and-evaluating-objects) and [methods](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html#dialog-build) for conditions inside Watson Conversation Service Official Documentation.